# Why do my SQL queries not agree with each other?

Tags: sql

Hoping this is something I can fix, or maybe someone can point out an obvious mistake.

I have two queries:

`SELECT HIDEORSHOW FROM tblProspects  WHERE PROSPECT_ID = 1261484;`

```
HIDEORSHOW
1
```

`SELECT PROSPECT_ID FROM tblProspects WHERE HIDEORSHOW = 1;`

```
PROSPECT_ID
196248
199004
204190
204338
210918
211932
213332
214186
216980
218254
222420
223578
223824
224429
224390
224672
224714
227031
227481
228363
230040
238168
239230
240790
241409
243827
244553
245785
247947
248349
250426
250640
252399
252555
253610
253949
254641
255109
```

Sorry for the long list I just want you guys to see the madness. Is there any reason why this would happen? There is another prospect that I know of, 1257506, that has this `HIDEORSHOW` value and does not appear in the list.

Comment: What is the column type for HIDEORSHOW? It could be that it is a string and not a number, and might actually contain whitespace. can you tell us the type of the column?

Comment: So id's > 999999 are not displayed?

Comment: Just checked HIDEORSHOW is defined as ENUM('0','1'), and modifying my SQL statement to use the string '1' gives me the correct result. I'll have to sort out the mystery of why I can use 1 and '1' later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would lay good money that the HIDEORSHOW field is a string of some kind, and that some values have leading or trailing spaces.

```
This is true,  due to implicit CASTing:      '1' = 1     (Becomes :  '1' = '1')
This is false, even with implicit CASTing:  ' 1' = 1     (Becomes : ' 1' = '1')
```

To test this, try this query (or it's equivalent in your version of SQL)...

```
SELECT PROSPECT_ID FROM tblProspects WHERE CAST(HIDEORSHOW AS INT) = 1;
```

This will force the casting to be `string => int` rather than the other way around.

Or you could try this test...

```
SELECT '<' + HIDEORSHOW + '>', LEN(HIDEORSHOW) FROM tblProspects WHERE PROSPECT_ID = 1261484;
```

You'll then have more visibility on the exact value in that field.

Comment: Depends on the DBMS, probably. The following returns two rows in SQL Server 2008 R2: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT ' 1' UNION ALL SELECT '1') s (f) WHERE f = 1`, i.e. the string is implicitly converted to a number, not vice versa.